# Why is checkbox replace owner on subcontainers and objects missing?

Tags: permissions, windows-10, file-ownership

I'm using Windows 10. I am trying to delete files from C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash, but to delete them I need TrustedInstaller permission so I tried to change ownership of files. When I go to Security -> Advanced -> Change(owner) owner is changed correctly, but there is no checkbox stated above.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting owner and clicking apply and then OK and again changing owner I managed to get Add button which permitted me to add permissions on specific user and delete file. Still there was no checkbox, but this time change link was accessible with administrator privileges. I believe Add button was greyed out because I didn't have admin privileges and buy changing owner to admin first time I somehow acquired them. Still I don't no why there is no checkbox.